# trigger que no permita modificar mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql y tengo que crear un trigger que no permita modificar una columna llamada nombre y si algun usuario de la base de datos la intenta modificar tengo que mostrar un mensaje por pantalla que diga "No se puede cambiar el nombre de socio."

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Pregunta sin tabla, sin columna, pidiendo un mensaje en pantalla quién sabe cómo, y sin esfuerzo alguno. Boeh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy la solución práctica a lo que necesitas:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_update_socios
  BEFORE UPDATE ON socios
  FOR EACH ROW
  set new.nombre=old.nombre;
```

Que puedes comprobar a partir de este dataset.

```
CREATE TABLE socios(
  id_socio int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  tlf varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO socios (nombre, tlf) VALUES
('Juan','666777888');

UPDATE socios set nombre='Paco'
  WHERE id_socio=1;
```

Para el mensaje de error, investiga un poco sobre tratamiento de excepciones, intenta algo, muéstranos tu código y, con gusto, continuaremos ayudándote.